# Why is no error output redirected from STDERR to file by my batch file?

Tags: windows, cmd, stdout, stderr

I have a simple health check script for checking status of windows share drives listed below.

I am getting the desired output when the command works. However, when there is an error, I do not get output in the output file. I have looked at STDOUT and STDERR as a possible solution, but I am not able get this to work yet.

Can anyone please help me with this code.

```
@echo off
echo START > results.txt
for /f %%s in (server_list.txt) do (
    echo %%s >> results.txt
    for /f "delims=" %%n in ('net use \\%%s') do (
        echo %%s - %%n >> results.txt 2> err.txt
    )
)
```

The output file looks like this.

```
START
server1
server1 - The command completed successfully.
server2
server2 - The command completed successfully.
```

However, there is nothing in the `err.txt` file. I have made sure to put some incorrect entries in file `server_list.txt` to get a few errors for testing. The error output is displayed in the command line window instead of being printed to the `err.txt` file.

Comment: echo is not going to write to stderr.  net.exe does, but you are not redirecting its output.  You'll have to re-think this, consider redirecting the output of cmd.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Second, the command **FOR** executes the command line `net use \\%%s` in a new command process using `cmd.exe` in background which means with no visible console window. The output of this background command process written to **STDOUT** is captured by **FOR** and processed next line by line. The error output written to **STDERR** is redirected by **FOR** to error output of currently running process which is the reason why the error output can be seen in opened console window of command process executing the batch file.

The command line `echo %%s - %%n >> results.txt 2> err.txt` outputs the output of background command process executing `net use` captured by **FOR** and assigned to loop variable `n` to **STDOUT** of current command process which is redirected to file `results.txt`.

Additionally the error output by command **ECHO** is redirected to file `err.txt` if **ECHO** would output an error message. But **ECHO** does never output an error message. That is the reason why `err.txt` does not contain any error message output by command **NET**.

I suggest to capture with **FOR** standard and error output of `net use` and evaluate the output in body of **FOR** loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
del err.txt 2>nul
echo START > results.txt
for /F %%I in (server_list.txt) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use "\\%%I" 2^>^&1') do (
        set "NetOutput=%%J"
        if not "!NetOutput:successfully=!" == "!NetOutput!" (
            echo %%I - %%J>>results.txt
        ) else (
            echo %%I - %%J>>err.txt
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

When the line output by command **NET** from any output contains the word `successfully` the line from `server_list.txt` and the success message is written to file `results.txt`. Otherwise the most likely error output is written also with line from `server_list.txt` to file `err.txt`.